# Pentaho Kettle Avro input

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

I was wondering if someone managed to make this step work?
For example i have local avro file with extension avsc that I want to read, but I can't.

this is the file, if someone can share example ktr how to read it?
Thanks

```
{
    "namespace":"$package.bi.ca.cp",
    "type": "record",
    "doc": "sample1",
    "name":"cp",
    "fields": [
    {
       "name":"cpi",
       "type": "string",
       "doc": "sample2"
    },
    {
       "name":"ci",
       "type": [
        "null",
        "string"

       ],
       "doc": "sample3"
    },
    {
       "name": "pmv",
       "type": [
         "null",
         {
           "type": "array",
           "items": "$package.bi.ca.cp.ckmv"
         }

       ],
       "doc": ""
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Which PDI version are you using?

Comment: I am using 8.1 version

Comment: try with 8.3, 8.1 is not a stable version.

Comment: Tried didn't help. Anyway thanks for answering.

Comment: can you tell us whether this is avro or avsc file.